# MySQL : increment a column by one after insert through a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So here it is guys,

I have four tables.

---

**My first one** :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
`Id_User` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id_User`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 ;
```

It contains the people's data.

---

**My second one** :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Subject` (
`PrimaryKey_Subject` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`Subject_Name`  int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`PrimaryKey_Subject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It contains the subject name : mathematic, science, biology, etc...

---

**My third one** :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Register` (
`ForeignKey_User` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ForeignKey_Lesson` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ForeignKey_User`,`ForeignKey_Lesson`),
 KEY `ForeignKey_User_I` (`ForeignKey_User`),
 KEY `ForeignKey_Lesson` (`ForeignKey_Lesson`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This one allows a user to register to a lesson.

---

**My fourth one** :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Subject_Annex` (
`PrimaryKey_Subject` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`Number_Registered`  int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`PrimaryKey_Subject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here it is,

How can I set a trigger that increment the **Number_Registered**  each time someone register to a lesson?

---

**For instance**,

I  create a user : John Doe --> **Users Table**.

- Then afterwards, I have my **Subject Table** which contains all the courses: mathematics, science, biology, etc...

I can now, register, through the **Register Table** my freshly created user to a subject : let's say science

Then now we have the **Subject_Annex Table**, which through **a trigger**, and once my user, *(John Doe)*, is linked to a subject, *(Science)*, is supposed to be able to show the amount of users that registered to the subject from, **(here Science)**,and also increase by 1 their number for each time someone register to this subject.

---

**So to make it short**,

How can I set a trigger that increments the registered number of user each time someone register to a subject ?

---

**For example** :

- Primary Key Subject : Science
- Number of registered : 1

(Someone else register)

- Primary Key Subject : Science
- Number of registered : 2

(Someone else register)

- Primary Key Subject : Science
- Number of registered : 2
- Primary Key Subject : Mathematic
- Number of registered : 1

Etc...

Comment: This is the wrong use of a trigger. There's no need to store a value (the count of registered users) when it can easily be retrieved using a SELECT statement or VIEW

Comment: Consider implementing `Subject_Annex` as a view querying how many people are currently registered for a course.

Answer (score -1):

**I managed to solved the problem by myself** :

```
DELIMITER |
create trigger before_insert_subject_annexe
before INSERT
on Register
for each row
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Subject_Annex (PrimaryKey_Subject, Number_Registered)
VALUES (NEW.ForeignKey_Lesson,  + 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  Number_Registered=Number_Registered+1;
END;
DELIMITER |
```

---

**Then on my Subjet_Annex Table** :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Subject_Annex` (
`PrimaryKey_Subject` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`Number_Registered`  int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`PrimaryKey_Subject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I added an unique key on **Number_Registered**

Comment: What if a user is "un-registered"? IOW, they drop the subject? Instead of creating triggers, you should focus on how you can use a select to get the actual number of people registered.

Comment: I just have to add a DELETE and decrease the value by 1

Comment: Very bad design. Poor use of MySQL resources.